# ¿Puede "mientras" indicar posterioridad en lugar de simultaneidad?

Tags: conjunciones

> Ella no estaba dispuesta a volver **mientras él no reconociera haber
>   mentido**

Estoy confundida. En este caso *mientras* no expresa simultaneidad, sino posterioridad, ¿verdad?

Answer (score 5):

En realidad sí que expresa simultaneidad. Piénsalo de esta forma: mientras se dé la condición (no reconocer haber mentido), al mismo tiempo se dará la premisa (no estar dispuesta a volver). En el momento en el que la condición falle (se reconozca la mentira) la simultaneidad se romperá y se podrá proceder con la ejecución de la premisa (estar dispuesta a volver).

Para indicar posteridad la frase se puede expresar de esta forma:

> Ella no estaba dispuesta a volver **hasta que** él reconociera haber mentido.

Comment: Curiosamente la forma como la mayoría de los Colombianos lo diríamos es "Ella no estaba dispuesta a volver hasta que él **no** reconociera haber mentido".  Esto me hace cuestionarme si esa negación es correcta, pero esa es la forma frecuente por estos lados.

Comment: @DGaleano en Colombia y en España también. Es la forma estándar aquí, se escucha en cualquier parte (incluso en traducciones oficiales), pero si lo piensas, no es la forma correcta. Me he cuidado de no poner esa negación de más en el ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Las siguientes oraciones son más o menos equivalentes:

> Ella no estaba dispuesta a volver **mientras** él no reconociera haber mentido.
>
> Ella no estaba dispuesta a volver **a menos que** él reconociera haber mentido.
>
> Ella estaba dispuesta a volver **siempre y cuando** él reconociera haber mentido.
>
> Ella estaba dispuesta a volver **si** él reconocía haber mentido.

En todas hay una condición que él debe cumplir para que ella vuelva. La única diferencia destacable es que el "mientras" de la primera oración incluye el factor temporal.

Por lo tanto, en tu oración el **mientras** no indica posterioridad sino una **condición de la duración** de una acción. Tal vez no es muy claro entenderlo como "simultaneidad", pero es exactamente eso: la acción de ella ocurrirá durante el tiempo que ocurra la acción de él.

(Aunque normalmente no se incluye el "mientras" entre las conjunciones condicionales (no la vas a encontrar), los programadores saben que es una palabra fundamental para definir estructuras condiciones. En cambio en gramática se considera adverbio y conjunción *temporal*.)

Answer (score 1):

Para una comprensión más fácil puedes quitar las negaciones, en este caso esto no alteraría el sentido de la oración para nada.

> Ella no estaba dispuesta a volver mientras él no reconociera haber mentido

Quedaría:

> Ella estaba dispuesta a volver mientras él reconociera haber mentido

Y de esta forma puedes ver más claramente la simultaneidad, es un poco confuso manejar dobles negaciones, siempre que puedas recomiendo simplificar de esta manera las oraciones.