# Cuando: ¿un nexo adversativo o temporal?

Tags: conjunciones

> Al contrario del principio, **cuando hubiera querido encontrarse** con
>   el enemigo invisible para convencerlo de sus errores, ahora sólo
>   quería hacerlo picadillo con las tijeras de podar.

¿Es **cuando** en esta frase un conector adversativo o temporal?

Comment: Me parece que adversativo (o sea, para contrastar una cosa con algo opuesto) **no es**: ya dijiste _al contrario_, que está cumpliendo esa función. Todo hace parecer que es temporal (la palabra _cuando_ está para referirse a tiempo).

Comment: ¡Hola y bienvenido a [spanish.se]! Esta y [tu pregunta anterior](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16876/1674) son la mar de interesantes. Tal vez te interese registrarte en el sitio para poder luego comentar las respuestas que recibes.

Answer (score 4):

Es **temporal**, se refiere al *momento* en el que hubiera querido encontrarse con el enemigo invisible (al principio).

"Cuando" es adversativo en una oración como la siguiente:

> Eres odiosa porque me traes peras cuando sabes que lo que yo quiero son manzanas.

Aquí es más o menos equivalente a un "pero".

Comment: "Pero" es conjuntivo, no adversativo. Creo que en la oración que pusiste de ejemplo, "cuando" también es conjuntivo.

Comment: @SantiagoTórtora: ¿Conjuntivo? No sé qué nomenclatura usas, pero tengo entendido que es una _conjunción adversativa_.

Comment: Tenés razón. Estaba pensando en conjunciones lógicas, no en lenguaje natural.

Answer (score 2):

La palabra **cuando** es un ejemplo de [conector temporal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conector_%28ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica%29#Temporales).

Conector adversativo es el que se usa para contrastar dos cosas opuestas: en esta misma oración se hace mediante la expresión *al contrario*.