# How to understand this "mientras"

Tags: conjunciones

I came across this sentence while reading Crónica de una muerte anunciada by Gabriel García Márquez.

> Se fueron **mientras** se calmaban los ánimos, según la decisión del alcalde, pero no regresaron jamás.

I thought I understood it with no issue, until I saw the corresponding part in the English version.

> They were leaving **until** spirits cooled off, according to the mayor’s decision, but they never came back.

The way I understood the Spanish sentence was something like this.

> They left **while** spirits were cooling down, according to the mayor’s decision, but they never came back.

Context-wise, and also from the way the sentence ends, the official English translation seems to make more sense. The subject is a family running away from where they were living soon after two sons committed an honor killing for their sister (like the next day) and “spirits” must not have been calming down yet.

However, I don’t quite understand the logic behind this interpretation. In my understanding, the verb *irse* refers to a punctual and non-durative act, and therefore, it should have no such thing as an end (to be marked by "until). Even if we accept that it implies that they are going to stay away for some period of time and that period has an end, I wouldn’t expect it to be marked by *mientras*. I would expect something like this.

> Se fueron **hasta que** se calmaran los ánimos, según la decisión del alcalde, pero no regresaron jamás.

I have little trouble understanding the sentence in this [question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16876/28954) as the verb in the main clause describes a state and the verb in the *mientras* clause is in the subjunctive. I can see simultaneity with an implied end.

In the above sentence, on the other hand, the verb in the *mientras* clause can be easily understood as referring to something that was already happening.

Is this a common usage of *mientras*?

---

[Edit]

OK, it seems I should have asked this question first: Is the English translation (with *until*) correct?

The sentence I made up with *hasta* was on the assumption that that was indeed what was meant by the original Spanish sentence. If that’s not the case and my interpretation (with *while*) is correct, then I can tell this usage of *mientras* is pretty common, of course.

Comment: Con "hasta", "until", no es correcta. Con "mientras", "while", si es correcta. "They left while spirits were cooling down, according to the mayor’s decision, but they never came back". Es correcta. Este uso de "mientras", es bastante común.  Yes, this usage of "mientras" is pretty common. You interpretation with "while" is correct.

Comment: They were leaving until spirits cooled off,= Not accurate: The existing translation is bizarre and sometimes translators go fast and do not realize their sentence doesn't make much sense. There is no hasta que here. mientras is while.

Comment: Como hablante nativo del español, para mí también tiene más sentido la segunda interpretación "while", en lugar de "until".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have translated it the way you did as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Cuestión:** ¿Es este un uso común de mientras ?

Is this a common usage of mientras?

---

- **Sí**, sí es común emplear "mientras" en ese sentido, pero hay que saber cuándo utilizarlo.

Parece que en la pregunta,

"*Ella no estaba dispuesta a volver mientras él no reconociera haber mentido*"

no han explicado correctamente los usos de "mientras", solo han puesto ejemplos similares. Son sin duda malas respuestas. Abajo te voy indicando las distintas variedades de "mientras" y de tus distintas anotaciones. Quizás en tu observación influya que sea, simplemente, una mala traducción o la redacción del libro bajo la editorial que estas leyendo. Así que ten paciencia para leer lo que sigue.

Perdón por lo extenso, pero son muchas preguntas y no son fáciles de explicar.

"**Mientras", no siempre se entiende como un "Hasta". El espacio temporal es distinto**.

---

**"Hasta"** puede ser;

- **Adverbio**

Equivale a "*incluso*" y en ese caso es compatible con otras preposiciones.

Ejem. Es tan bueno, que puede conducir la moto **hasta** (incluso) con una rueda.

- **Preposición**

Establece relaciones subordinadas entre una palabra y un complemento.

Ejem. "Corrió hasta el coche".

---

- "**HASTA QUE**"

La locución "**hasta que**" es una *locución conjuntiva* y esta formada por la preposición "hasta" y la conjunción "que".

Locuciones conjuntivas formadas por una preposición y la conjunción "que";

Hasta que, desde que, para que, sin que, con que, etc. Estas unidades aparecen separadas o unidas, según su uso.

---

- **Oración de Aguijonazo**

"They were leaving until spirits cooled off, according to the mayor’s decision, but they never came back".

- / "H**asta que**"

"Se fueron "**hasta que**" se calmaran los ánimos, según la decisión del alcalde, pero no regresaron jamás". / **Incorrecto**.

En este caso " hasta que", introduce un espacio temporal en el que debe de cumplirse una condición, en este caso", la condición es que se calmen los ánimos. Así, si tu dices; "*Se fueron hasta que se calmaron los ánimos*", estas manifestando, que después de que las personas se fueran, hubo un momento en el espacio temporal que los ánimos por fin se calmaron, y por tanto, se cumplió esa condición, por eso es "hasta que".

Se entiende que ellos no podían volver "hasta que" la condición se cumpliera.

Para indicar eso mismo mejor;

Según la decisión del alcalde, se fueron "**hasta que**" se calmaran los ánimos. Sin embargo, jamás regresaron.

---

- / "**Mientras**"

"Se fueron **mientras** se calmaban los ánimos"

En esta frase, como abajo aclaro, "Mientras", funciona como conjunción y esto significa que **expresa simultaneidad entre dos acciones**.

Esto quiere decir;

/ 1. Que esas personas realizan la acción de irse ó marcharse y...

/ 2....a la vez, (mientras tanto, mientras que pasa eso), se espera que los ánimos de estas personas se enfríen ó calmen.

El espacio temporal es distinto, es simultaneo o a la vez. Mientras ocurre una cosa, ocurre otra.

**"Mientras" - "While"**

*during the time that; at the same time as.

nothing much changed while he was away*

---

- **Oración Original**

Se fueron mientras se calmaban los ánimos, según la decisión del alcalde, pero no regresaron jamás.

---

- **La forma en que entendió la oración en Español aguijonazo**.

"Se fueron mientras se calmaban los ánimos, según decisión del alcalde, pero nunca regresaron". / **Correcto**

"They left while spirits were cooling down, according to the mayor’s decision, but they never came back". / **Correcto**

- **Oración que esperaba aguijonazo** (Explicada más arriba)

Se fueron hasta que se calmaran los ánimos, según la decisión del alcalde, pero no regresaron jamás. /**Incorrecto**.

*Implícitamente, cuando dices que "se fueron" y luego "hasta que", estas indicando que se fueron hasta que se cumplió la condición (la de calmarse los ánimos), dejándose entender que luego volvieron. Sin embargo, si continuas diciendo que jamás regresaron, entonces la frase se convierte en algo entendible, pero confuso*.

---

Esta frase se encuentra en el número 2 de los diferentes "Mientras" que abajo se especifican;

- 2 / Como **conjunción**, **expresando simultaneidad entre dos acciones**.

"*Se fueron mientras se calmaban los ánimos, según la decisión del alcalde, pero no regresaron jamás*".

---

- **Oración Explicada**

/ Versión corta para una mejor comprensión

Mientras se calmaban los ánimos, según la decisión del alcalde (ellos) se fueron, pero (ellos) no regresaron jamás.

/ Versión larga para una mejor comprensión.

**Mientras** (mientras pasaba un poco de tiempo y) **se calmaban los ánimos**, (ellos)  **se fueron según la decisión** (tomada por el alcalde) **del alcalde**, **pero no regresaron jamás** (pero ellos nunca regresaron (pero ellos jamás volvieron)).

---

Clases de "**Mientras**"

Puede funcionar;

- 1 / Como **adverbio de tiempo**

Como adverbio, es palabra tónica (significa que la "e" de mi**e**ntras tiene más fuerza) y se escribe aislada por comas del resto del enunciado:

Ejem. «* María, mientras, hablaba por el teléfono móvil.*».

Ejem. "**Ella no estaba dispuesta a volver, mientras,** **él no reconociera haber mentido**"

- 2 / Como **conjunción**, **expresando simultaneidad entre dos acciones**.

Como conjunción, en cambio, **mientras** es palabra átona, es decir, la "e" de "mi**e**ntras" no se pronuncia con tanta fuerza, y no se separa con coma del verbo que introduce.

Ejem. «Todo esto lo hace Pablo mientras mezcla colores y aceites».

Ejem. "Se fueron mientras se calmaban los ánimos, según la decisión del alcalde, pero no regresaron jamás".

- 3 / **Mientras tanto**, tiene el mismo sentido que el adverbio temporal "mientras", el número 1 de más arriba.  La locución adverbial.

Ejem. **mientras tanto** «*El Señor Gómez, mientras tanto, permaneció inmóvil y con los nervios a flor de piel*».

Ejem. "**Ella no estaba dispuesta a volver mientras** (mientras tanto) **él no reconociera haber mentido**"

- 4 / **Mientras más - Mientras menos**. (...más ....más), (más....menos), (...menos...más...), (...menos...menos).

Se utiliza en el sentido, de "cuanto más", ´"cuanto menos". En Iberoamérica, en algunos lugares, "Entre más".

Ejem. "Cuanto más estudio más aprendo".

Ejem. "Cuanto más quiero menos quiere".

Ejem. "Cuanto menos veo más leo".

Ejem. "Cuanto menos oigo menos me entero de lo que dicen".

P.D.

- 1 "Ir"/"Irse" El verbo puede ser "intransitivo" "**Ir**" y como  verbo pronominal, "**Irse**", es decir, se puede conjugar de manera reflexiva como *irme, irte, irse, irnos...*. Los significados pueden variar.
- 2 "spirits” / No son espíritus. No se si es una buena traducción, un error o puede confundirse con "anima", "anima/animo", que significa alma, espíritu, aunque "animo" puede ser una acepción. Por aclararlo, simplemente, en este caso es "Animo", "los ánimos", en el sentido de humor (estado de ánimo), la actitud ó disposición de la gente a realizar algo, en este caso miedo a que hubieran venganzas por parte de otras personas.
- 3 Puede ser que la traducción realizada del libro, no sea la mejor. Buscaría otras editoriales ó traducciones.
- 4 "Ella no estaba dispuesta a volver mientras él no reconociera haber mentido" **Adverbio Temporal, puedes cambiarlo por "Mientras tanto** ó "en tanto". En esta frase,  igualmente, si es posible intercambiar "mientras" por "hasta que", ya que la condición "reconocer haber mentido", es muy clara.  Espero te haya servido.

Comment: Pero no dije “se calmaron” sino “se calmar**a**n”.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry. Lo siento. Ya esta cambiado, pero el cambio del verbo no invalida el sentido general de la frase con "hasta". Gracias